# How do different kernel versions change the compilation process of C files (other than by having different versions of gcc)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, gem5

I am trying to compile gem5's m5threads, but I am getting compilation errors due to it only being compatible with Linux kernel version 3.19 (and gcc version 4.8). I am using Linux kernel version 5.4, but I am using an older version of gcc (gcc-4.8 and even gcc-4.4), and yet I still get build errors (I know people have still gotten this to work with older linux kernel versions from an issue opened up on the m5thread repository).

What other effects do different linux kernel versions have on compilation using gcc other than the actual version of gcc being used (which can be changed)? I have included the makefile below (in case that offers additional insight).

```
CC = gcc-4.4
CFLAGS = -O3 -static

.PHONY: all clean

all:  libpthread.a(pthread.o)

clean:
        $(RM) *.o libpthread.a
```

Here are the build errors:

```
gcc-4.4 -O3 -static -c -o pthread.o pthread.c
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_rwlock_init’:
pthread.c:380: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:381: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:382: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_rwlock_rdlock’:
pthread.c:398: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:404: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:405: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:406: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:407: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:411: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_rwlock_wrlock’:
pthread.c:422: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:426: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:432: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:433: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:433: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:434: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:435: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:439: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_rwlock_unlock’:
pthread.c:448: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:449: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:451: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__writer’
pthread.c:454: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:454: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__nr_readers’
pthread.c:456: error: ‘struct __pthread_rwlock_arch_t’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_cond_init’:
pthread.c:536: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:537: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__futex’
pthread.c:538: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__nwaiters’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_cond_broadcast’:
pthread.c:549: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c: In function ‘pthread_cond_wait’:
pthread.c:556: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__futex’
pthread.c:557: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__lock’
pthread.c:558: error: ‘struct __pthread_cond_s’ has no member named ‘__nwaiters’
: recipe for target 'pthread.o' failed
make: *** [pthread.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What would really offer additional insight would be samples of the build error messages you're getting!

Comment: I think it has more to do with the glibc version. I don't think it will compile for glibc-2.26 or later (and possibly earlier).

Comment: @SteveSummit I have included the build errors I am getting in my original question.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for the glibc suggestion. I will look into this.

Comment: Are the systems __exactly identical__ and differ only in kernel, or are these two different systems? How do you know it's the kernel, and not _anything_ else? `pthread.c:380: error:` post the content of the source file - please create an [MCVE]. `I am using an older version of gcc` So, another difference, seems like one system has two gcc versions, the other has one gcc version.

Comment: Yeah, re @IanAbbott's comment, the errors are about the (supposedly opaque) `pthread` structs not being defined the way that m5thread expects.  The pthread library is part of glibc, not gcc; I don't think the gcc version has anything to do with this problem at all.  My guess is that the kernel version is not strongly related either.